# Serialize a custom List to JSON and deserialize the same to that custom list using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, windows-store-apps

In my Windows 8.1 app I want to store the result of my custom generated List optimally to my local storage so that I can retrieve it later on even after the app closes.
The Newtonsoft JSON serializer helps me in serializing the List to string format  that I can store in any text file. But deserializing it wont fetch the required List.

**Class**

```
  public class BookDetailsItem
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public ImageSource CoverImage { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Visibility ProgressVisi { get; set; }
            public List<StoryDetailsItem> stories { get; set; }
        }
    public class StoryDetailsItem
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }           
            public ImageSource CoverImage { get; set; }
            public string Time { get; set; }
            public string Word { get; set; }
            public Visibility ProgressVisi { get; set; }
        }
```

Now I am adding my required items to a list of this class

```
List<BookDetailsItem> tempbook = new List<BookDetailsItem>();
tempbook.Add(......);
```

Now Serializing it I can store it in any txt file

```
string tempstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempbook);
```

But deserializing it how can I get back the same List all I am getting is an object which isnt in correct format

```
var obj1 = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(tempstr));
```

Is there any other way in which I can store these data in Local storage more easily and optimally(without creating a SQlite database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BookDetailsItem>>(tempstr)
```

To give the deserializer the type information.

Comment: Ty for such a fast reply much appreciated  but since my list has an imagesource type I am getting this error on Deserializing it using this :-
Unable to find a constructor to use for type Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '[0].CoverImage.DecodePixelType', line 1, position 44.

Comment: Ah. This means that `ImageSource` is not serializable, as it's an abstract class. You could instead save the source-url as a string, and have a readonly property for the imagesource which will generate the bitmapsource when requested. Or save the image as 64-bit encoded string (or byte array) much the same way. Alternatively, you could try something like [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) and see if it handles the images.

Comment: then change property of ImageSource to byte[] or base64 string and convert it to ImageSource in client  ....

Comment: Yes removing my Imagesource from class itself fixed the problem will try to save it to a folder or base64 image as suggested. Ty man for such a faster reply you rock.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible to serialize an ImageSource object.

try saving it as a byte[]

Comment: Being a noob havent used byte[]. Will try to convert my bitmap images to bytes and bytes to bitmap to be able to set them as  ImageSource. But the problem is most of the images that I receive are in .png format along with having to specify a pixel height and width but since my images can be of different dimensions will it be the right choice?

Comment: saving it into a folder and only storing the location in your json would also work since the byte[] (byte array) can be quite large. the dimensions/type won't matter. that will be fixed automatically when reading the stream of bytes. (search for byte[] to image source conversion)

Comment: Yes thats the option that was in my mind but saving all those unique images inside a different folder would take some time to code. Could you please also let me know is this the right way to store my data optimally and for offline usage or do I need to follow some other steps.